# XNA: How to convert a game to be compatible with the Xbox 360?

Tags: xna, xbox

I have a C# XNA game that I'd like to test on the 360. How do I do this, in terms of what I need to do to the Visual Studio project?

For instance, how can I define certain actions will only take place on an Xbox? Something like:

```
# if XBOX
   // do stuff
# endif
```

Answer (score 3):

MSDN Documentation on XNA provides all the answers you need.

[Connecting your Xbox 360 Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975643(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx), and [Developing Cross-Platform Games](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282471(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx) (which includes [Cross-Platform Game Project Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976061(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx) and [Cross-Platform Conditional Compilation Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that there are other things you should be checking such as multiple controllers, the player one controller not being PlayerIndex.One and supporting XBOX 360s with multiple storage devices (including when a user pulls out one of those devices).

The XNA creators forums have an "evil checklist" for making sure your game meets some basic requirements on the 360. http://creators.xna.com